# CSS Issue in wrapping contenteditable div around Floating image

Tags: html, css, css-float, contenteditable, word-wrap

I have a problem in floating a contenteditable div around a image. Here's my code:

HTML:




Section title

CSS:

```
.fl {
    float: left;
}

.rgtDiv {
    min-height: 300px;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
}
```

I want the `rgtDiv` to have left border at the right end of the image but right now it appears at the left end of the image.

When I click on the `rgtDiv` the cursor goes to the image and not inside the `rgtDiv`. How to make the cursor come inside the `rgtDiv`?

Also the border of the `rgtDiv` applies to the entire parent Div. How to make it to apply only for the `rgtDiv`.

Can anyone help resolving my problem?

Here's my jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/n8WJ2/

Thanks in advance!

yadav

Answer (score 0):

try giving the rgtDiv a float: left; and a width ...
should work and don´t forget to clear your floats

Comment: Add display: inline-block to your rgtDiv css rule and also give that class to the div you are trying to affect.

Comment: If you just want to surround the image with your content, then just move the div with the img into the content div.

Comment: @Kevin, if i float the rgtDiv and set width, when i type content more than one line inside rgtDiv, then rgtDiv comes below the image.

Comment: @nocturns2, I want the image out of the content div as i am going to apply CKEditor plugin for that content div. display:inline-block also causing the rgtDiv to come below the image when i type more content.

Comment: You can't wrap a border around an image.

Comment: What you want to do is not possible because of the float situation. You should read more about floating a div and what happens with that div and so on -> http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can add this:

```
.rgtDiv {
    position: relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    min-height: 300px;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n8WJ2/4/)

It will resize depending of the width of the image.

Comment: Thanks drip! But i want the content to wrap around the image. This is not wrapping the content around image

Answer (score 0):

Try this

HTML

```
<div>
 <div class="section-title">Section title</div>
 <div class="rgtDiv">
  <img src="http://www.destination360.com/north-america/us/montana/images/s/great-falls.jpg" height="300" width="300"/>
 <div contenteditable="true" class="editableblock"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.fl, .rgtDiv img  {
 float: left;
}

.rgtDiv {
 border: solid 1px #ccc;
 display:block;
}

.editableblock {
 min-height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Now it wraps the text around the image but if i apply border to editable block, it is applying to the whole container along with image. Is it not possible to apply border to editable block alone?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still cares.
To workaround the issue with caret position, you can add zero-width space to the div in HTML:

```
<div contenteditable="true" class="rgtDiv">&#8203;</div>
```

and restore it every time user clears it:

```
$('.rgtDiv').keyup(function(){
    if($(this).text().length == 0){
        $(this).text('\u200B');
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/md9pf1sb/1/)

Answer (score 0):

`overflow: hidden` can be used for the contenteditable block :empty pseudo-class.
Please note that it has to be really empty: no spaces or tabs inside, just `<div contenteditable="true"></div>`